# exception.ToString() not returning any information

Tags: .net, exception

I have an exception in production that is not producing any log content.  We've had errors in production that have logged fine in this catch block, but for some reason, this particular exception (and I have no idea what it is) does not log anything. Here's the catch block:

```
//catch any exception and add it to the list of exceptions, and process next id
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (exceptionMessageBuilder.Length != 0)
    {
        exceptionMessageBuilder.AppendLine("----------------------------------------");
    }
    exceptionMessageBuilder.AppendFormat("Error occurred in processing id {0}.\n", currentID);
    exceptionMessageBuilder.AppendLine(e.ToString());
}
```

The only output I'm getting is "Error occurred in processing id d455e51f-6c86-4591-b75e-a2d29be73f4c."  The application finishes and sends this as an email so it's not bombing completely.

Normally I get message like:

```
Error occurred in processing id 593abf56-5057-400e-bbfb-da819df59710.
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Is there any reason why I would not get information?  Is it possible to catch a null exception?

Comment: You may want to append an additional line that indicates what the actual class of the exception is (`exceptionMessageBuilder.AppendLine(e.GetType().Name)`). The default `Exception.ToString()` implementation will, at minimum, contain the exception class, so the fact that nothing is being written at all might indicate a custom exception class that has overridden `ToString()` itself, possibly incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks dlev.  I took a look through some of the source code and I'm pretty sure that what's happening.

Comment: You may also want to loop thru any **inner exceptions**, too.